# Limit to number of items using 'IN' SQL syntax in arcmap/arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, sql

I'm writing a python script that uses `'NOT IN ('a', 'b', ...)'` statements on very large lists (like comparing 500 items in one feature class against >10k items in another) and am getting weird unexpected results (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and it corrupts the geodatabase...?!?).

I've looked and can't find any ArcMap/arcpy documentation on how large a list can be using IN/NOT IN syntax and was wondering if anyone knew. Using ArcGIS 10.3.1 with 64-bit python.

Update: All of the data in question is stored in file geodatabases.

Comment: +1 It also takes awful amount of time to execute long tuple queries.

Comment: If there are duplicates in your lists, you might want to have a look at using sets instead.  According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists), sets are faster for determining if an element is in a set.

Comment: from my experience the number of items ArcMap will accept in `IN` or `NOT IN` is around the 2000-2500 range.  I wouldn't advise using that many

Comment: The limit depends on the data source -- RDBMS engines impose their own limits (e.g. Oracle 1000).  Please edit your question to specify the data source.

Comment: IN is powerful, but inefficient in large numbers (especially in comparison to a JOIN query).  If you know you have a large list, compile a table with the keys instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit imposed by the Select By Attributes window in ArcMap is 26114 symbols. I have just generated a list of integers and pasted in the dialog box:

```
range_length = 4000
selection_tuple = str(tuple([x for x in range(range_length)]))
```

Now just paste into the dialog box and see how it is truncated (`...` replaces the sequence, just to keep it short for posting here):

```
OBJECTID in (0,1,2,3,4...3884,3885,3886,3)
```

Regarding Python, I am able to execute this code both in Python 32 and 64 bit. Tests done on ArcGIS 10.3.1. Doing selection both with **Make Feature Layer** and **Select Layer By Attributes** having in the selection tuple 100K+ items is no problem at all.

```
import arcpy
import random

range_length = 210000
values = [x for x in range(range_length)]
random.shuffle(values) #get randomly sorted values
selection_tuple = str(tuple(values))

print('selection length feats',range_length)
fc = r'C:\GIS\temp.gdb\Streets' #400K+ lines

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Default.gdb"
where_clause = '''ReqField IN {0}'''.format(selection_tuple)

#either works fine
#fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,where_clause=where_clause)
fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc) #takes 3-5 secs
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fl,"NEW_SELECTION",where_clause)

l = fl.getOutput(0)
print('feats count:', int(arcpy.GetCount_management(l).getOutput(0)))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(l,"range_{}".format(range_length))
```

**One thing to note is that having an index calculated on your field will speed up significantly the selection (this is what I've found from my tests)**. So, check whether you have the index calculated on the field you are doing selection.

In terms of performance, the Make Feature Layer with the IN statement in the where clause takes the following time to execute (the fc with 2.5mln rows is used with randomly generated numbers in range (1,10K):

```
range_length = 2000000 #13sec on Python 32bit
range_length = 1000000 #7sec
range_length = 500000 #3sec
range_length = 2500000 #11sec on Python 64bit
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I'll wait a bit to accept to see if anyone is aware of a hard limit in arcpy, but it sounds like whatever the limit is for your system for items in a python list, so presumably it's huge.

Comment: I've added some of the time metrics; you will be OK with several millions in the `IN` list. The selection / where clause will work just fine in several seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off using a table join to select your data. Given you already know all the elements you're looking to select against you can create a csv file with a column name, and each of the items as one row, e.g.

```
id
123
456
```

Load the table into ArcMap, and join the csv to the original dataset. You can choose to either only keep the features that join, or keep all features and select the features with an attribute query on the null fields, e.g.

```
"csv.id" IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the underlying database.

With an SDE *Oracle* database we measured a limit of ~1000 elements, while an SDE connection to *SQL-Server* could handle much more entries. A *personal geodatabase* (*.mdb) accepted a resulting sql of ~28k characters.

Those are only observations, maybe they depend on the DBMS configuration.